# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'mov_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

have a question related with the 2 tables which are **movie** and **categories**

categories are belong to movie which mean i can set many kind of categories for the movie.

So in the categories models, I put this code

```
public function movie(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Movie', 'mov_id');
}
```

which I want to set categories.mov_id = movie.id

On Controller Part, validation is fine off course show the error message when i put blank. But the problem is cant save to database and display **mov_id doesn't have a default value**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'cat_title' => 'required'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('category/create')
            ->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
        $movie = new Category();
        $movie->cat_title = Input::get('cat_title');
        $movie->save();
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created!');
        return Redirect::to('category');
    }
}
```

and last, here is the view file

```
                   <div class="table-container">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('category.store') }}"  role="form">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="cat_title" id="cat_title" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="分类">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit"  value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                                    <a href="{{ route('category.index') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-block" >Back</a>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Category schema

```
        Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('cat_title');
        $table->integer('mov_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The image of error message:-
[image]

Comment: Can you add the proper error what are you exactly getting

Comment: `belongsTo` means that each category table row is related to exactly one movie. That does not seem like what you indended. It makes more sense to say `belongsToMany` to say that a category is related to many movies and vice versa or (if a movie has a single category) say a category `hasMany` movies

Comment: You have pass mov_id in your form as a hidden field

Comment: Please post category table schema and the full error message

Comment: @ArzebMansuri Could you briefly show the example ?

Comment: @SapneshNaik updated the category schema.

Comment: @lun7code you should add mov_id to your store function or add NULL for default value on DB. $movie->mov_id = 1 like that.

Comment: @apokryfos So , I need to set has many for movie model?

Comment: @guvenakcbn oh thank! yup. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

The error msg tells you exactly what the problem is.  You are trying to insert a category record, but your form does not include a `mov_id` value.  Your schema specifies that `mov_id` is an integer, but does not specify any default value, nor that it can be null.  So Laravel does not know what to use for `mov_id` if you don't tell it, so it can't create a record.

The quick fix is to update your schema to [allow null values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#column-modifiers) for `mov_id`:

```
$table->integer('mov_id')->nullable();
```

But I think you're going to have bigger problems.  A category probably should not have a movie ID at all - that would mean that every category could have at most 1 movie.

I think what you really want is a many-to-many relationship between movies and categories.  That means one movie can have many categories, and one category can be assigned to many movies.

The [Laravel docs describe it well and include an example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).  You'll need to update your Laravel relationships:

```
// Category model
public function movie() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Movie');
}

// Movie model
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

And your schema:

```
Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title');
    // ... etc
});

Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('cat_title');
    // ... etc
});

Schema::create('category_movie', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('category_id');
    $table->integer('movie_id');
});
```